# Variable HTTP/HTTPS Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm sure this is just a simple Javascript scoping issue (go figure), but I've tried several different ways and can't seem to get this to work.

The idea is that the Express.js server defaults to HTTP with the call to express.createServer(), but optionally switches to HTTPS upon detection of *./conf/cert.pem* and *./conf/key.pem*.  I'm using asynchronous calls to Node's *path.exists()*, whereby the second callback argument contains the boolean result.

I have them nested currently so that a HTTPS server isn't created until it's "safe" (we know the outcome of whether the two files exist or not) since no ordering is guaranteed otherwise.  However, as I mentioned, I've tried several different ways, but I can't seem to modify the outer **app** variable.

I'm sure there's a simple fix that I'm not seeing right now, but any help would be appreciated!

```
app = module.exports = express.createServer();

path.exists('./conf/key.pem', function(exists){
    var keyExists = exists;
    path.exists('./conf/cert.pem', function(exists) {
        var certExists = exists;
        if (keyExists && certExists) {
             app = express.createServer({
                key: fs.readFileSync('./conf/key.pem'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('./conf/cert.pem')
              });
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not ideal. You shouldn't create a regular http server only to have it overwritten by an https server. I think the problem you're referring to comes from the fact that you're setting the `app` variable below, but not `module.exports`. So `module.exports` still refers to the original server created. This is what you should do:

```
var app = express.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./conf/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./conf/cert.pem')
});
module.exports = app;
```

There's no reason to check whether the files exist first. If the files don't exist, readFileSync will just throw an ENOENT. There is also no reason to do anything asynchronously before you have even entered the event loop.

I don't know why you would want your server to conditionally be https, but to do something similiar to what you were trying to do there:

```
var app;
try {
  app = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./conf/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./conf/cert.pem')
  });
} catch(e) {
  if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') throw e;
  app = express.createServer();
}
module.exports = app;
```

Or, this might look nicer:

```
var app;
if (path.existsSync('./conf/key.pem')) {
  app = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./conf/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./conf/cert.pem')
  });
} else {
  app = express.createServer();
}
module.exports = app;
```

Remember, doing things synchronously is fine as long as you don't have to serve a million requests at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the path.existsSync() method! I was actually viewing an old version of the documentation (stemming from me being lazy and Googling for the link rather than navigating to the Node homepage :D ) that didn't have the synchronous version.  It sure makes things easier!  While the code is certainly cleaner / less hazardous now, I'm still having the same scoping issue. Even after *module.exports = app*, app is undefined when it gets down to the *configure* block.

Comment: **Update**: Figured it out. Works great now, thanks! And to address your previous note, running the HTTPS server depends on the certificates being generated prior.  While I intend to make a build process in the future that automates everything, I'm circumventing the dependency in the meantime.  Further, although I picture most instances operating over HTTPS, I don't want to pigeon-hole the end-user into not being able to use regular HTTP if so desired. Eventually I'll create some sort of configuration file to specify an explicit choice.